# Save the state of UITableView Button

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, cell, nsuserdefaults

In my app the user is able to like a TableView Cell "Like Button". But What I want to do now is save the cells that are liked and keep them as liked or unliked for when the user leaves the app and returns later at anytime. I have tried nsuserdefaults all day and it will not work. I've read up on coreData but no idea what route to take next. Anyone who can help I'd be beyond grateful.

I want to save the state that the cell was in when the user left the app for when they return. I want to learn how to save the cells that been liked locally somehow.

[Watch Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVC_UrFRyBxjZ3DVkhGZ2RHoRdMI2Ps7/view?usp=sharing)

ViewController.swift -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var dataSource: [TableModel] = []
    var updatedCell = TableViewCell()
    var updatedIndex = Int()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    
        self.dataSource = Array(repeating: TableModel(isLiked: false), count: 8)
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonSelected(_ sender: Any) {
        dataSource[(sender as AnyObject).tag].isLiked = !dataSource[(sender as AnyObject).tag].isLiked
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (sender as AnyObject).tag, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        updatedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        updatedIndex = indexPath.row
        
        let vc = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "secondVC") as? moreInfoViewController)!
        vc.delegate = self
        
        let isLiked = dataSource[indexPath.row].isLiked
        if isLiked {
            vc.isLiked = true
        } else {
            vc.isLiked = false
        }
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        //        cell.moreBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        cell.likeBtn.tag = indexPath.row
//        cell.likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        // Get Each Cell Liked Button Status and display if the user liked or not Liked each cell
        let isLiked = dataSource[indexPath.row].isLiked
        if isLiked {
            cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}

// Conform VC to protocol (VC2Delegate) located in "Structs.swift" File
extension ViewController: VC2Delegate {
    func likeStatusDidChange(_ vc2: moreInfoViewController, to title: Bool) {
        // set the text of the table cell here...
        dataSource[updatedIndex].isLiked = !dataSource[updatedIndex].isLiked
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: updatedIndex, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

moreInfoViewController -

```
import UIKit

class moreInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var backBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var theImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var mainlikeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var mainTypeLbl: UILabel!
    
    var isLiked = Bool()
    weak var delegate: VC2Delegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        styles()
        
        // "isLiked" variable to display whether or user liked this event
        if (isLiked == true) {
            // is Liked
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            // Not Liked
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
    }
    
    // Heart/Like Button Action. User can like event in this VC with this button and it will tell the firstVC (ViewController) to update "Like Status" there also
    @IBAction func likeBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if (isLiked == true) {
            // is Liked
            isLiked = false
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            isLiked = true
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        delegate?.likeStatusDidChange(self, to: true)
    }
    
    // Go Back To FirstVC (ViewController)
    @IBAction func previousVC(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func styles() {
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        locationLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        locationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        backBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
        theImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        theImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
        theImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

I have this Code For saving the data. This Code is ran when the user liked a cell. It saves the data but when I leave the app and come back. The saved data is cleared/reset. I am saving the cells ID#

```
// Add To Array When User liked A Cell. Cells ID
if (!IDArray1.contains(String(eventID[indexPath.row]))) {
    IDArray1.append(String(eventID[indexPath.row]))
    defaults.set(IDArray1, forKey: "key101")
    print("Saved Data: \(defaults.stringArray(forKey: "key101") ?? [String]())")
}
```

Like Button Tap Code (Also Located in the ViewController Code) -

```
let isLiked = dataSource[indexPath.row].isLiked
if isLiked {
    // User Liked Cell
    cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
} else {
    // User UnLiked Cell
    cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
}
```

Comment: Both UserDefaults and Core Data are able to achieve what you need, so let's dive into details. When you say that UserDefaults "will not work", what does it mean? Did you get compilation errors, runtime errors or it just wouldn't do what you intended? Could you please include some code that didn't work?

Comment: My code ran successfully. But the array I was trying to save through “ UserDefaults” would save the array sometimes and not save it other times. Was not consistent

Comment: I added the NSUserDefaults code

Comment: Post your likeButton Tap Code

Comment: Okay, edited in at the bottom

Comment: the thing is. It saved it randomly. So sometimes it will work and then sometimes it won't

Comment: if you are using a table view or collection view you need to use a model and pass it to your list , in your case you need a model which is an array of objects and then pass each item of that model to your table view cell inside the cell for row function