# nsuserdefaults data is being reset/cleared when I return to app

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults, local-database

I am trying to Save a String Array with NSUserDefaults. Basically in the app my user can Like a post, which then the post ID # gets saved to an array string list. The Array saves while in the app. But once the user leaves the app and closes it and then returns, the saved data is now empty.

My IDArray1 and defaults variable is global.

[Wach Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVC_UrFRyBxjZ3DVkhGZ2RHoRdMI2Ps7/view?usp=sharing)

```
// Add ID# to array when user likes post
if (!IDArray1.contains(String(eventID[indexPath.row]))) {
    IDArray1.append(String(eventID[indexPath.row]))
    defaults.set(IDArray1, forKey: "key101")
    print("Saved Data: \(defaults.stringArray(forKey: "key101") ?? [String]())")
}
```

In my viewdidLoad() I read the saved data

```
print("Saved Data: \(defaults.stringArray(forKey: "key101") ?? [String]())")
```

Comment: Are you synchronizing userDefaults; `defaults.synchronize()`

Comment: No I am not. What does that do? Can you elaborate

Comment: No need to synchronize now; Apple don't recommend this. How are you getting the data?

Comment: JSON parsing. But even if it was an app without data. I am just trying to only save the state of the like button for when the user terminated the app. I aded a video of what I mean.

Comment: Make your video public and update the code with how are you fetching the data

Comment: Here is the code in a post from yesterday.https://stackoverflow.com/q/67227379/15709097 And video is public? Try again and let me know :)

Comment: Please post the code where you read the data from user defaults.

Comment: it is in this link :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/67227379/15709097

Comment: my apologies. I added it to the code above

Comment: `key102` and `key101`are not the same. You should use more descriptive names or – still less error-prone – static constants in a struct.

Comment: ohh yes those are all the same keys  my code. I copied that from my updated code rn. But yes they are all the same keys