# How to save array data locally

Tags: swift, core-data, datasource, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code. I want to learn how to save my dataSource for the like button of each cell. So that when the user leaves the app and returns later, the same cells that were liked remain liked.

This is new code from my last post. Since I don't want to keep making new arrays, I can try and locally save my dataSource variable which stores each cells Status of being liked or not.

ViewController -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var dataSource: [TableModel] = []
    var updatedCell = TableViewCell()
    
    var updatedIndex = Int()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        
            self.dataSource = Array(repeating: TableModel(isLiked: false), count: 8)
            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
            self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonSelected(_ sender: Any) {
        // Update Cell for which UIButton (Like Button) was tapped.
        dataSource[(sender as AnyObject).tag].isLiked = !dataSource[(sender as AnyObject).tag].isLiked
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: (sender as AnyObject).tag, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        // Saved updatedCell & updatedIndex variables for delegate pattern. To Update this VC's cells data when edited on secondVC (moreInfoViewController) in a way, made them accessible outside this function
        // To Get Specific TableView Cell the user is interacting with.
        updatedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        updatedIndex = indexPath.row
        
        // Go to Second VC and Send cell tapped data to next view
        let vc = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "secondVC") as? moreInfoViewController)!
        vc.delegate = self
        
        // Get Status of Liked Button in the cell the user tapped and display if the user liked it previously in the SecondVC
        let isLiked = dataSource[indexPath.row].isLiked
        if isLiked {
//            print("Liked")
            vc.isLiked = true
        } else {
//            print("Not Liked")
            vc.isLiked = false
        }
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        //        cell.moreBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        cell.likeBtn.tag = indexPath.row
//        cell.likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        // Get Each Cell Liked Button Status and display if the user liked or not Liked each cell
        let isLiked = dataSource[indexPath.row].isLiked
        if isLiked {
            // User liked the post
            cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            // User Unliked the post
            cell.likeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}

// Conform VC to protocol (VC2Delegate) located in "Structs.swift" File
extension ViewController: VC2Delegate {
    func likeStatusDidChange(_ vc2: moreInfoViewController, to title: Bool) {
        // set the text of the table cell here...
        dataSource[updatedIndex].isLiked = !dataSource[updatedIndex].isLiked
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: updatedIndex, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

moreInfoViewController -

```
import UIKit

class moreInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var backBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var theImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var mainlikeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var mainTypeLbl: UILabel!
    
    var currentID:String = ""
    var isLiked = Bool()
    weak var delegate: VC2Delegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        styles()
        
        // "isLiked" variable to display whether or user liked this event
        if (isLiked == true) {
            // is Liked
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            // Not Liked
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
    }
    
    // Heart/Like Button Action. User can like event in this VC with this button and it will tell the firstVC (ViewController) to update "Like Status" there also
    @IBAction func likeBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if (isLiked == true) {
            // is Liked
            isLiked = false
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unLiked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            isLiked = true
            mainlikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "liked"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        // When User interacts with like Button, this function gets called that tells the firstVC (ViewController) to update as well.
        // likeStatusDidChange function is located at the bottom of the (ViewController) with extension ViewController.
        delegate?.likeStatusDidChange(self, to: true)
    }
    
    // Go Back To FirstVC (ViewController)
    @IBAction func previousVC(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func styles() {
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        locationLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        locationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        backBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
        theImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        theImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
        theImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Save the state of UITableView Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67227379/save-the-state-of-uitableview-button) and [nsuserdefaults data is being reset/cleared when I return to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235514/nsuserdefaults-data-is-being-reset-cleared-when-i-return-to-app), Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: It’s a different piece of code buddy

Comment: Sorry if that set you off. Just trying to find the best solution for the problem I came across.

Comment: Will your data source always contain 8 elements?

Answer (score 0):

When you get array from userdefaults it gives you `Any` type array so you need to cast it to `Int` array and check it nil or not before you use. So you can use this code block.

```
    if let savedDataKey = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "savedDataKey") as? [Int]  {
    print(savedDataKey)
}
```

Comment: Okay so that works, but I'm still having an issue to where I add an element to the array right before I restart the app, but when I restart the app and return, sometimes the new elements won't be there

Comment: I don't get it. You said even you use this code you still can't get the elements when you restart the app?

Comment: Yes I do get the elements. But randomly an element won't be added when the user likes a post. Its frustrating it decides randomly when not to listen. Get me?

Comment: You are checking is liked status from another array which name is datasource but you didn't change like status of object in datasource array. Because of that some times your if block not working I guess. You need to focus on that part because, saving and gettin data part looks like correct.

Comment: Well not really. I am sending the post ID to an array. and when the user opens the app then I have my code to where (if array contains ID# then its a post they liked)

Comment: and if its a post they unliked then the ID# gets removed from the array

Comment: is it better to save datasource locally and get liked Status there?

Comment: Yes thats better you have lots of array and that is confusing. You have like status of your item you don't need to seperate their id's to another array.

Comment: So how do I save that locally even when the app is terminated? Sorry Still learning

Comment: If you don't save anything to userdefaults, file system or core data, everything will be deleted when you terminate the app.

Comment: Okay I updated my code above so that you can see my dataSource code. Thank you for helping me so far. Now I know I do not need to make more arrays just to save the liked data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231536/discussion-between-james-chritian-and-alihan).